# How would you define "earthy humor"?

Tags: meaning

Please provide at least two examples. Very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Without more context, in particular the surrounding sentence, it’s impossible to say.

Answer (score 1):

Earthy has many definitions. But specifically with regard to humour it's likely to mean something specific. Here are definitions from two dictionaries, specifically pay attention to definitions 3 and 4 respectively:

> 1. Of, consisting of, or resembling earth: an earthy smell.
> 2. Of or characteristic of this world; worldly.
> 3. Crude or off-color; indecent: an earthy joke.
> 4. Hearty or uninhibited; natural: an earthy enjoyment of life.
> 5. Unadorned and simple in style: an earthy homemade stew.
>     [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/earthy)
>
> 1. of the nature of or consisting of earth or soil.
> 2. characteristic of earth: an earthy smell.
> 3. realistic; practical.
> 4. coarse or unrefined: an earthy sense of humor.
> 5. direct; robust; unaffected.
> 6. Archaic. worldly; earthly.
>      
>     [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/earthy)

Definition 3 in the first one uses "joke" as an example use, and Definition 4 in the second one uses "sense of humour" in its example.

Based on this I think you can infer its meaning. I think off-colour is a good adjective. Other words describing it could be risque and vulgar.

Comedians might refer to this style as "working blue" or "blue comedy", however in my opinion this has stronger connotations than earthy. Earthy to me sounds milder.

Blue comedy is found in the "Ribaldry" Wikipedia article, in case you want to look it up.
[Blue comedy, Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribaldry)